# Looping on Document nodes (Including childrens )

Tags: javascript, html, dom, document.write

I'm trying to replace "document.write" inside an iframe that contains an ad.
I'm currently parsing the html string via "DOMParser" and i'm getting a dom document in return, i would like to loop on this document and insert each node and any childrens to the real iframe dom.
But i've encountered two problems:
1.if the string from the original document.write doesn't contains `<head><html><body>` the "DOMParser" api adds them anyway.
2.i can loop on all nodes like this:

```
ParsedHtml.querySelectorAll("*").forEach(function(node) {
```

but i'm getting on the first iteration the  `<html>` node with all the nodes as childrens and also the `<body>` node again with all children nodes, and when the iteration continues i'm getting to the same nodes again.
so what i really like to do is to parse the string from document.write and start inserting node after node including all childrens directly to the iframe dom in the correct order (head first the body ...) 
Thanks !

Code example:

```
var RealDocumentWrite = document.write;
document.write = function(str){
//call our parser here instead of using document.write
}
//our parser:
function Parser(str){
var parser = new DOMParser();
ParsedHtml = parser.parseFromString(str, "text/html");
ParsedHtml.querySelectorAll("*").forEach(function(node) {
//in this for loop the problems that i specified above occur
}
```

Example execution:
if our input will be :

```
var samplehtml = '<html><head><script>console.log(1);</script></head><body><div id="111"></div></body></html>'
```

and we use `console.log(node);` inside the for loop the output will be :

https://ibb.co/hxzDc8

as you can see in the first iteration the node is the entire html tag including all childrens (head body...) the second is only the head than just the script inside the head than the entire body and than just the div inside the body .
so thats not good for me at all , i need to parse the string as a document and start appending the nodes in the correct order to the iframe thats it

New code:

```
 ParsedHtml.querySelectorAll("head > *").forEach(function(node) {
        IframeDoc.head.appendChild(node);
    });

    ParsedHtml.querySelectorAll("body > *").forEach(function(node) {
        IframeDoc.body.appendChild(node);
    });
```

Comment: Maybe you just want to select `head *, body *` instead? (Or `head > *, body > *`, depending on specifics.)

Comment: There are two cases to consider , the head and the body , i can doo ParseHtml.head and ParseHtml.body but when i loop over them i can't get the childrens of some nodes that have childrens .

Comment: This is very vague. Please show a [mcve] that makes it clear what and where exactly your problem is.

Comment: @CBroe i have edited the code, thanks

Comment: Still not clear what exactly the problem is now. Please create an _actual_ example including test data, and describe where exactly it goes wrong and how.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for the feedback i've updated it again

Comment: Still don’t see how what I initially suggested would not easily fix the issue … https://jsfiddle.net/fL6uceh3/4/

Comment: @CBroe your solution is actually pretty good but when i'm using appendchild to append  each node in the loop to the iframe dom , nodes with childrens will not appended correctly the childrens will be gone.

Comment: Appending a node to a document automatically includes all the content of that node as well - so I think you should not have to append those lower level children individually in the first place. With `head > *, body > *` you would only get the actual children of those elements, not ancestors further down.

Comment: @CBroe now it does works as expected but the ad code doesn't render at all , no errors or something just blank.
i guess maybe the javascript isn't working properly but i can't figure out why...
if i'm inserting script tag with console.log i can see the output so the javascript is executing. am i missing something?
btw if i'm using document.write to insert the html to the iframe everything is working properly , i just can't tell whats the difference

Comment: @CBroe i just compared the iframe dom with native document.write and my implementation and a lot of elements are missing probably because the ad creates them dynamically via javascript but i just don't see why this doesn't work that way.

Comment: Maybe script elements that “create” further content don’t get executed properly, or something like that … hard to say without an actual, fullexample. // Are you more or less doing the ad service providers work for them here, or what is the eventual purpose of this? It should be rather their responsibility to get their code updated in such regards.

Comment: @CBroe I'm trying to solve a known problem because the ad code uses document.write but i load it asynchronously so the document.write call actually destroy the document so i'm trying to make it work async